# How to align y2labels right or according to the decimal point in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have some of numbers negative and some positive.

```
set format y2 "%2.3f"
```

does not help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `help format specifiers`. Just add a space after `%` and the number of spaces you would like to have, here `1`. This will places a space in front of positive numbers, where negative numbers have the `-`.

```
set format y2 "% 1.3f"
```

If you want to have it perfectly aligned, you'd better use a monospace font.